# Is it possible to override module CSS in Drupal 7 without modifying actual CSS files?

Tags: css, module, drupal-7, h5p

i have installed Drupal 7 and want to override css of specific tag of h5p CSS but can you help me to solve this issue.
want to override the CSS file of module without modifying actual CSS files.
I have created custom module but with the help of custom module,i am able to override the Themes CSS but not any MODULE CSS.

i want solution of module css changes

Comment: I suggest to consult the official documentation at https://h5p.org/node/2692 and https://h5p.org/drupal-customization